# Como fazer consultas de senha criptografada no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Bom, criei uma função chamada **buscaUsuario** que deveria encriptar a senha do usuário e compara-la com o banco de dados porém sempre que executo recebo o erro:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\almoxarifado\banco-usuario.php on line 9

**Função**

```
function buscaUsuario($conexao, $email, $senha){
    $hash = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "select * from usuarios where email='{$email}, senha='{$hash}'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    if(password_verify($usuario, $hash)){
        echo "Valid";
    } else {
        echo "invalid";
    }
    return $usuario;
 }
```

Como eu poderia fazer essa função comparar o Hash gerado com o hash que está no banco de dados e ainda confirmar se o login foi valido ou invalido?

Estive pensando em fazer o meu banco de dados me devolver o valor cadastrado no campo senha atribuindo ele á uma variável para eu poder usar o `password_verify($user_senha, $hash)` e verificar se o hash gerado pelo usuário é o mesmo que o cadastrado no banco. Daria certo?Se sim,como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua querie me parece ter um erro de sintaxe.

**Está assim :**

```
"select * from usuarios where email='{$email}, senha='{$hash}'";
```

**O correto seria :**

```
"select * from usuarios where email='{$email} AND senha='{$hash}'";
```

Levando em consideração que no cadastro do usúario você tenha guardado em sua tabela a hash gerada pela funcão `password_hash`, o script corrigido ficaria assim:

```
function buscaUsuario($conexao, $email, $senha){
    $query       = "select * from usuarios where email='".$email."'";
    $resultado   = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $row_cnt     = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    if($row_cnt > 0){
        $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        /*$senha é o valor digitado pelo usúario e o $usuario['hash'] salvo 
        anteriormente no banco de dados*/
        if(password_verify($senha, $usuario['hash'])){
            echo "Valid";
            return $usuario;
        }else{
           echo "invalid";
           return false;
       }
    }else{
       echo "Não existem usuários com o login informado.";
       return false;
    }
}
```

Créditos por correção a @Inkeliz, melhore e adapte a seu gosto!

Comment: O correto seria remover o `AND senha='{$hash}'`, porque o BCrypt tem um salt inteiro, o que vai fazer com que o  `$hash` seja sempre diferente.