# Condição de login com usuário ou e-mail no mesmo campo

Tags: php, mysql, email, login

Estou criando um sistema para escolas, onde o professor ao se cadastrar insere dados como nome,e-mail,usuário e senha. Até agora o professor pode logar com e-mail, mas gostaria que pudesse fazer o login com o nome também(eu fiz alterações mas esta dando erro pois não sei como criar a condição).

PAGINA do LOGIN:

```
<form method="post" action="login2.php">

  <div id="pagina">
  <p align="left">Digite seu Email:
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login"  value="" />
</p>

  <p>Digite sua senha:
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" />

  </p>
  </p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="tooltip-inner" value="Fazer Login" />
  <div id="erro">
  <?php echo isset($_REQUEST["erro"]) ? $_REQUEST["erro"]: ""?>
  </div>
  <a href="recuperacao.php">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
  </p>
  <p>Não tem uma Conta?<a href="cadastro.php">Criar usuario. </a></p>
  <p>

  </p></form>
```

PAGINA de CONFIRMAÇÃO DE LOGIN:

```
    <?php
include "CONEXAO.php";

 $login= $_REQUEST["login"];
 $senha = $_REQUEST["senha"];

 $sql = "select * from professor where login= :email ou login= :usuario and senha= :senha";

 $result = $conexao->prepare($sql);
 $result ->bindValue(":email", $email);
$result ->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario);
 $result ->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
 $result ->execute();

 $qtde = $result->rowCount();

 if ($qtde ==1)
 {
     session_start();
     $linha = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $_SESSION["cod.professor"] = $linha ["cod.professor"];
     $_SESSION["nome"] = $linha ["nome"];

     header("location: perfil.php");
 }
 else
 {
     header("location: login.php?erro=E-mail ou senha invalidos.");
 }

?>
```

Comment: Não existe condição "ou" no mysql, troque por "OR"

Answer (score 5):

Quando você tem mais de uma condição válida, normalmente se usa o `OR`, mas tem que tomar cuidado com o agrupamento:

```sql
SELECT * FROM professores WHERE (:login=email OR :login=usuario) AND senha= :senha;
```

Sem os parênteses você pode ter problemas sérios de um lado do OR validar só pelo login, sem considerar senha quando não for fornecido o usuário:

```sql
SELECT * FROM professores WHERE :login=email OR :login=usuario AND senha= :senha;
--                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                                    | Se isso for verdadeiro, o resto das condições
--                                    | acaba sendo ignorado e a pessoa loga sem senha
```

**Tem jeito mais simples:**

O mais simples é usar o `IN`, e isto vale para quantos campos quiser:

```sql
SELECT * FROM professores WHERE :login IN (email, usuario) AND senha= :senha
```

Independente do que foi perguntado, armazenar senha no DB sempre é uma péssima idéia Veja mais nos links a seguir:

> [Como fazer consultas de senha criptografada no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223467/70)
>
> [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Answer (score 2):

Na sua query tente fazer desta forma

```
$sql = "select * from professor where (login= :email or login= :usuario) and senha= :senha";
```

Não existe nenhuma condição `OU` a condição que deve de usar é `OR`

Comment: Obrigada pela informação dos parênteses, não estava funcionando bem até coloca-los.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, você deve especificar quais campos da sua tabela professores corresponde ao campo e-mail e login. Então a query deve ficar

```
$sql = "select * from professor where login= :login or email= :login and senha= :senha";
```

Como não estou muito familiarizado com o `:` para representar um valor, em forma de variável, seria assim:

```
$sql = "select * from professor where login='$login' or email='$login' and senha= $'senha'";
```

> O ***:login*** ou ***$login*** deve ser a condição para pesquisa dos dois campos porque você usou a variável ali em cima para requisitar a informação dos inputs e armazenou nesta variável:

```
$login= $_REQUEST["login"];
```

Comment: Obrigada, eu nem havia percebido meu erro. Eu fiz as alterações ao fazer o login agora aparece um erro na linha 12, que seria o código $result->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver os erros que eram as variáveis no result, o código ficou assim:

```
$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
 $senha = $_REQUEST["senha"];

 $sql = "select * from professores where (email= :login or usuario= :login) and senha= :senha";

 $result = $conexao->prepare($sql);
 $result ->bindValue(":login", $login);
 $result ->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
 $result ->execute();
```

Obrigada