# Login com CPF e CNPJ

Tags: php

Meu código abaixo esta funcionando. No entanto, perceba que eu possuo o campo `CL_Cpf` e preciso adicionar outro que é `CL_Cnpj`. Sendo assim, necessito que os dois funcionem no mesmo campo `input` e faça login no sistema.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Código:

```
if(isset($_POST['documento']) && empty($_POST['documento']) == false) {
$documento = addslashes($_POST['documento']);
$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);

 $dsn = "mysql:dbname=Provider;host=********l";
 $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "*******";

  try {
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Provider.Cliente WHERE CL_Cpf =    '$documento' AND CL_Email = '$email'");
  if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {

    $dado = $sql->fetch();

   $_SESSION['documento'] = $dado['CL_Cpf'];
   $_SESSION['email'] = $dado['CL_Email'];
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Falhou: ".$e->getMessage();      
}  
}
?>
```

Comment: Por que tem tantas vírgulas no seu texto? Não seria mais simples usar a pontuação correta para separar as orações? Quanto ao código, o que tem a dizer do e-mail? Ele parece ser um campo de login atualmente, mas não o citou na pergunta. Ele deverá ser mantido ou não?

Comment: obrigado pela resposta Anderson, sim o email sera mantido, o login contem cpf e email, porem quero que contenha, cpf, cnpj e o email , quando a pessoa digitar cpf ou cnpj ele vai validar e logar no sistema

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297464/condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-login-com-usu%c3%a1rio-ou-e-mail-no-mesmo-campo

Comment: Como o próprio @AndersonCarlosWoss falou... você pode validar usando OR, só tomando cuidado para validar o que é cpf, cnpj ou email do input... 
`''SELECT * FROM Provider.Cliente WHERE CL_Cpf =    '$documento' OR CL_Email = '$email' OR CL_Cnpj  = '$VAR'"`

Comment: @ReynaldoMansi ou um `WHERE '$documento' IN (CL_cpf, CL_cnpj)` (vide meu link acima)

Comment: @Bacco eu acho a opção do  `In` bem melhor mesmo e mais prática, só queria ilustrar o  `OU` como uma questão de lógica mesmo

Comment: @ReynaldoMansi melhorei a resposta do outro link para cobrir as 2 situações

Comment: @ReynaldoMansi e aproveitei pra fazer um alerta para os ( ), pq o OR é um perigo se a pessoa não souber agrupar. Imagine o desastre se o autor não atentar pra isso :D

Comment: Muito obrigado !  seria muito eu pedir como fazer o select correto ?  rsrs ..seria assim ??

Comment: $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Provider.Cliente WHERE               '$documento' IN (CL_cpf, CL_cnpj) AND CL_Email = '$email'");

Comment: não funcionou !!!

Comment: ok resolvido desta forma         $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Provider.Cliente WHERE (CL_Cpf= $documento or CL_Cnpj= $documento) AND CL_Email = '$email'");